# Adding detailed request information in Google Cloud Trace

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-trace

I'm building a Spring Boot application that's deployed on Google App Engine. To find out the cause of some weird latency issues, I figured I'd enable Google Cloud Trace to view detailed latency reports.

Adding basic tracing was simple enough since this is supported natively by GAE. However, I am having a hard time adding details to any individual trace.

For example; the following code:

```
public MediaContent getMediaContent(long contentId) {
    Optional<MediaContent> found;

    try (Scope ss = tracer.spanBuilder("databaseSubSpan").setSampler(Samplers.alwaysSample()).startScopedSpan()) {
        tracer.getCurrentSpan().addAnnotation("Retrieving MediaContent " + contentId + " from repository");
        found = mediaContentRepository.findById(contentId);
    }

    if (found.isEmpty()) {
        tracer.getCurrentSpan().setStatus(Status.NOT_FOUND);
        throw new NoSuchContentException(contentId);
    }

    return found.get();
}
```

I figured that in the Cloud Trace UI, this would display a separate little latency line so I could see which part of the total request time is spent on database communication. However, no such information is visible to me:

[image: Google Cloud Trace screenshot]

I have made sure that this exact method is invoked by adding a few log entries around it. All the log entries (even the one inside the `try` block) show up in my logs.

I set the sampling rate to 100% by adding the following to my `application.yml`: `spring.sleuth.sampler.probability: 1.0`

Basically, what I expected to see on the Cloud Trace UI is a second bar underneath the primary request. As such:

[image: Expected result]

Is this even possible in Cloud Trace? I expect that it would be since the chart is so tall which seems to me like it has space left for extra bars. If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the configuration of your tracer? Also, did you enable full sampling yet? You can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/java#always-sample) to see the sample codes of tracer configuration. Let me know if you still have concerns.

Comment: @ShawnDiWu I was hoping that the `application.yml` setting I mention in the post would be enough to enable full sampling. I have now added the code from the link you mention but unfortunately I still do not see the additional details that I expect.

Comment: I guess you miss “.setSampler(Samplers.alwaysSample()).” to enable full sampling.

Please check [this document](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/io.opencensus.trace.samplers.Samplers).

Comment: @AhmadP I was hoping to use the `application.yml` setting to manage the sampling rate for different environments. Anyway, I added the alwaysSample snippet and it is still not uploading additional details.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be investigated by the Google product team.

Then I would suggest forwarding this through a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for further support. or you can [open a ticket with Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) (For free users [this link](https://cloud.google.com/support/)) so that we may investigate this issue further.